# Odoo create invoice from picking with XML-RPC call

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc

I would like to create an invoice from the picking but trough and XML-RPC call from a PHP file. 
I have tried to call the action_id: 359 like this:

```
$transfer = $rpc->button_click($uid, $pwd, 'stock.invoice.onshipping', 'invoice_open', array(111));
```

But it doesn't work... Do some one have any clue on how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Below i am posing the code it may help in your case:

In Php you can try `ripcord` library :
For Basic connection setup/authorization  just type this code.

```
$url = "http://localhost:8072";
$db ="my_db";
$username = "prakashsharmacs24@gmail.com";
$password = "7859884833";
$common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/common");
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());
echo $uid;//1
```

Now create a model instance and call the work flow by `exec_workflow`:

```
$models = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/object");
$models->exec_workflow($db, $uid, $password,'account.invoice' ,'invoice_open',14);
```

Hope this may help in calling the workflow from php.